# Why does any OpenCv (C++) substract operation result in a full black image?

Tags: c++, linux, opencv, image-processing

I want to start with that I am certainly no beginner using OpenCV. But I have been mostly using it in C#, and now I am completely lost on a simple issue on the C++ variant that I cannot seem to solve...

Issue: Whenever I use any operation that will subtract one image from another, the output image is 100% black. With 1 in 50 images showing partly the expected result, but also partly being full black (I will link example images in the end). To clarify, with full black I mean every pixel value 0. I am expecting quite some visable noise after this operation, but none is present.

Here is my simple piece of debugging code:

```
Mat moveImage, stillImage, subst;

while(capture) {
  moveImage = CameraClass::cameraVector[0]->imageList.front().clone();
  stillImage = CameraClass::cameraVector[0]->imageList.back().clone();

  cv::resize(moveImage, moveImage, Size(moveImage.cols * 0.5, moveImage.rows * 0.5), INTER_LINEAR);
  cv::resize(stillImage, stillImage, Size(stillImage.cols * 0.5, stillImage.rows * 0.5), INTER_LINEAR);

  cv::addWeighted(moveImage, 1, stillImage, -1, 0, subst, CV_8UC1);

  stringstream ss, ss2, ss3;

  ss << path + "/camtest/image" + to_string(ui32FrameCount) + ".png";
  ss2 << path + "/camtest2/image" + to_string(ui32FrameCount) + ".png";
  ss3 << path + "/camtest3/image" + to_string(ui32FrameCount) + ".png";

  string filepath1 = ss.str();
  string filepath2 = ss2.str();
  string filepath3 = ss3.str();

  cv::imwrite(filepath1, moveImage);
  cv::imwrite(filepath2, stillImage);
  cv::imwrite(filepath3, subst);
}
```

My results here are 2 perfectly nice images being saved from *moveImage* and *stillImage*, while *subst* is just completely black.

The addWeighted option is already an attempt to solve it from my side. I have also tried:

`cv::subtract(moveImage, stillImage, subst);`

And also the C++ operation:

`subst = moveImage - stillImage;`

All resulting in the same result, black images. I tried adding the images in all these different ways, and the output result is completely fine. So it must be something with the subtract operation and perhaps values dropping below 0? But a CV_8UC1 MatType should  truncate below 0 values automatically right?

Here are some example images and results:

[Partly black, partly noise (Had to amplify the noise or else it got lost in upload compression)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PAZi2.png)

[100% black image result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eOgRs.png)

[moveImage frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RYm8U.png)

[stillImage frame 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/emsKE.png)

Additional information that could be important:

1. My code is Threaded/Asynchronous. This exmaple piece of code is in one thread and isolated though. Since moveImage and stillImage are fine I do not see why other threads or code could badly influence my subtract operation. *Subst* only exists in this piece of code and is not used or accessable anywhere else.
2. I am not releasing my Mat resources at the moment. I have tried doing that in the debugging process but it made no difference in the results.
3. Right now all 3 Mat variables are declared once before the loop of this code and then used over and over. I don't know if that could be an issue, but I also already tried declaring them again in each loop.
4. Every loop of this code stillImage and moveImage are updated with a new frame from a camera. Maybe the subtract operation somehow keeps a reference somewhere instead of a copy?
5. The size of moveImage and stillImage is exactly the same and does not change throughout the runtime.

Comment: can you try cv::absdiff function? This will definitely lead to non-zero elements if the images aren't identical. It can easily happen that your input code leads to multiple images sharing the same memory which would mean stillImage and movingImage are actually identical. Are the linked images input or output (imwrite) of your function?

Comment: can you share `GetNewFrame` code and the code how that buffer is filled? Can you check whether bufferLength doesnt lead to the same image, e.g. `GetNewFrame(0)` == `GetNewFrame(bufferLength)`? (btw. are you sure that indexing is right? Typically a buffer would be indexed either by 0-indexing so that bufferLength-1 is the last index, or by 1-index so that 1 is the first index??? If it is some kind of circular buffer, maybe element(bufferLength) isnt the last but the first element (index overflow)?

Comment: @Micka I tried the AbsDiff and it still results in mostly black images. I looked at the output of both stillImage and moveImage and they are constantly changing (different noise). But perhaps indeed they are the same once they arrive in the loop. 

My image getting was a placeholder because of function names. I will edit the question for a better representation

Comment: whether images are the same or not you can easily check from your saved images in filepath1 and filepath2, but make sure that ui32FrameCount doesnt change between generating the individual pathes. If cameraVector[0]->imageList.front() and cameraVector[0]->imageList.back() isnt the same (e.g. size of the list is == 1) and images dont share their memory, the code should imho be ok. If I use your linked images with your addWeighted command I get non-0-entries all over the result image.

Comment: @Micka I accidentically did not link exmaple images from the same frame number. But I looked at the file size and suddenly noticed that at every index the files size is eactly the same for stillImage and moveImage. So somehow they do seem to be the same image after all perhaps! I edited the post to include the move and still image from the same index. But I guess the debugging goes towards my list code then.

Comment: @micka I looked into my imageList code and found the culprit... I wrote a char[] of image data into a Mat and then added that mat to the imageList. That char[] was a memory pointer though, so every new frame the entire imageList was updated with the same image. Cloning the Mat before adding it to the imageList solved the problem! Thank you for the suggestions and questions leading me to focus on the real issue. Can you write an answer that I can select to give you the proper credit? :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can easily happen that `cv::Mat` share their data memory within lists or arrays so that if on of the images is updated, all the images still point to the same memory. For example if capturing updates the same cv::Mat element in every iteration and this cv::Mat is pushed back to a list or vector without deep-copying the pixels (with `.clone()` or `.copyTo()` ).

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> buffer;
cv::Mat img;
while(true)
{
    bool success = capture.read(img);
    //buffer.push_back(img); // in this case Mat objects will share their memory!
    buffer.push_back(img.clone()); // this one is ok
}
```

Another, less common case is to initialize a cv::Mat with known image size and to create a container with a specific size and a default-object. In that case, all the objects will share their data memory.

```
cv::Mat img = cv::Mat::zeros(cv::Size(knownWidth, knownHeight), CV_8UC3);
// WARNING: this initialized element creation will lead to shared memory between different Mat objects in the buffer!
std::vector<cv::Mat> buffer(BUFFER_SIZE, img);
```

The reason in both cases is that cv::Mat is basically some reference counting smart header which can be copied without the need to copy underlying pixel memory space, so an explicit deep-copying of data is necessary if memory shall not be shared.

For debugging of such cases:

Make sure that within your function/loop, both images aren't identical. You can do that with cv::absdiff and thresholding the result by > 0. If there are any white pixels, the image content isnt identical.

Comment: Thank you! After trying the absdiff and still finding mostly black images it made me realise it might not actually be an issue with the subtraction. After then checking the saved images on the same index they appeared identical!

I then started checking the way I wrote data into my cv::Mat's and ended up finding they were indeed all referencing to the same data pointer!

It was a data issue after all and not an issue with the subtract function. Maybe I am more rusty with my C++ than I thought :)